# among other impacts to human, animal and plant life

Tags: prepositions, commas

In the following sentence, should there be a comma following "impacts"? If not, should the "to" after "impacts" be changed to "on"?

> They added it was more likely that global warming would surpass 2°C, a threshold that climate scientists say would bring catastrophic extreme weather events, among other **impacts** to human, animal and plant life.

Comment: Not an answer:  I would insert a comma and use "on" rather than "too:. I might also want to  stress the fact that humans are animals, so perhaps write "human and other animal and plant life".

Comment: Not at all. impact to something, no commas.

Comment: I agree with Lambie, I disagree with Ethan Bolker

Comment: Does it make sense to say "bring catastrophic extreme weather events to animal and plant life"?

Answer (score 1):

> They added it was more likely that global warming would surpass 2°C, a threshold that climate scientists say would bring catastrophic extreme weather events, among other impacts to human, animal and plant life.

Without a comma after *impacts*, the preposition phrase *among other impacts to human, animal and plant life* is treated as an interruption to the main clause preceding it.  Removal of an interruption should not affect the flow of the main passage.

> They added it was more likely that global warming would surpass 2°C, a threshold that climate scientists say would bring catastrophic extreme weather events.

This is fine.

With a comma after *impacts*, the preposition phrase *among other impacts* is treated as an interruption to the main clause.

> They added it was more likely that global warming would surpass 2°C, a threshold that climate scientists say would bring catastrophic extreme weather events to human, animal and plant life.

This passage is fine too if the interruption is removed.

Edit after Comments by @Andy Bonner

In the first case, catastrophic extreme weather events would happen.

In the second case, catastrophic extreme weather events would be brought to human, animal and plant life.

The change in meaning is very slight as catastrophic extreme weather events are understood to impact lives.

Comment: This is the right answer for pointing out that the comma could be included or omitted, with a change in meaning, but I think it needs to spell out more clearly that it does change the meaning.

Comment: @Andy Bonner, I have edited and explained the slight change in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

No, the sentence is correct.

"human, animal, and plant life" is the indirect object of the verb "impacts."

It is correct to write "(verb) to (indirect object)" without any commas.

Commas are needed within the indirect object because it is a list of three items. If it were only a single item, there would be no commas at all, as in "impacts to human life."